# Open source app with Laravel Passport. How to protect client secret?

Tags: laravel, react-native, oauth, jwt, laravel-passport

I am about to open source a React Native app which interacts with a Laravel backend in production.

However, the client_secret from [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) to generate auth tokens is saved in cleartext in the React Native repo.

What security should I be concerned about and are there best practices I should consider? Is it possible to import keys from .env into React Native project? Surely anyone who downloads the app would be able to get those keys anyway?

Comment: maybe use .env in your react native app: goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv (create a new repo omitting any secrets)

Comment: You should use Laravel Sanctum instead of Passport for you react app. Sanctum has been created for spa. Having client_secret on the front side readable by every one is a bad practice

Comment: I am using react native mobile app, not react spa

Comment: @Thomas if you want to post an answer I will give you the correct vote for it, thanks!